# Pygame import error in pyenv 2.7.11 on Arch Linux

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, importerror, archlinux, pyenv

I installed pygame on my Arch Linux machine with the following command:

```
$ sudo pacman -S python2-pygame
```

I am using pyenv and the version of Python in my virtual environment for this project is 2.7.11

When I run my program

```
$ python smartcab/agent.py
```

here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smartcab/agent.py", line 2, in <module>
    from environment import Agent, Environment
  File "/home/alex/machine-learning/projects/smartcab/smartcab/environment.py", line 5, in <module>
    from simulator import Simulator
  File "/home/alex/machine-learning/projects/smartcab/smartcab/simulator.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my own Arch Linux machine...

I have created a 2.7.11 virtualenv using pyenv and installed `python2-pygame` with pacman. With my virtualenv activated, I couldn't import `pygame` from python. So I was able to reproduce your issue.

After that, I tried downloading and compiling **pygame**'s source with `python setup.py install` without success. It is complaining about a missing `linux/videodev.h` which seems to be (from what I found on the web) deprecated and replaced by `linux/videodev2.h` (which is there).

I won't go further, I hope this will help someone finding the solution.